# Which is the best way to get a previous, current and next item from a Java List

Tags: java, list

I have an object User

```
User
 id: Integer
 nickname : String
 score: Integer
```

And a List of Users order by score:

```
id  name    score
3   John    90
2   Mike    80
4   Davi    30
5   Ana     20
6   Jane    10
```

I need a function that returns the User with Id passed by params, previous value and next

eg.: prams id = 4:

```
2   Mike    80
4   Davi    30
5   Ana     20
```

But when the id has the max score return

eg.: prams id = 2:

```
3   John    90
2   Mike    80
4   Davi    30
```

I need always return a list with 3 values

Which is the best way to make this function?

Comment: You cannot have multiple return values in java. Please specify how you want the objects to be returned from the method.

Comment: I want a List of users with  3 users

Comment: This is a flat-out XY problem. You just want to display 3 users within range of a given user on a sorted list. You can do this through a simple reference to the index (and thus adjacent users are `i-1` and `i+1`, for example), or sublists, or many other ways. But don't restrict yourself to one solution before you've realized what the problem actually is (you'll get more headaches than you deserve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything special for this, just a simple loop.

```
public static List<User> getThree(List<User> input, int id) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < input.size() && input.get(i).id != id) i++;
    List<User> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(input.get(i - 1));
    res.add(input.get(i));
    res.add(input.get(i + 1));

    return res;
}
```

This of course assumes that there are no illegal cases, where `i - 1` or `i + 1` could be out of bounds, but you can add in checks for that, like

```
if (i - 1 >= 0))
```

or

```
if (i + 1 < input.size())
```

before the corresponding lines.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are multiple ways, but this is one of the way to implement it :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class User{
    int id;
    String nickName;
    int score;
    User(int id, String nickName, int score){
        this.id = id;
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.score = score;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(id).append(" ").append( nickName ).append(" ").append(score);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class JavaList {
    
    Map<Integer, Integer> idxMap;
    List<User> users;
    
    public JavaList() {
        idxMap = new HashMap<>();
        users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User(3, "John", 90));
        idxMap.put(3, 0);
        users.add(new User(2, "Mike", 80));
        idxMap.put(2, 1);
        users.add(new User(4, "Davi", 30));
        idxMap.put(4, 2);
        users.add(new User(5, "Ana",  20));
        idxMap.put(5, 3);
        users.add(new User(6, "Jane", 10));
        idxMap.put(6, 4);
    }
    
    public List<User> findThreeRecords(int id){
        if (! idxMap.containsKey(id)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid User id");
        int index = idxMap.get(id);
        List<User> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (index-1 >= 0) resultList.add(users.get(index-1));
        resultList.add(users.get(index));
        if (index < users.size() ) resultList.add(users.get(index+1));
        
        return resultList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaList javaList = new JavaList();
        List<User> res = javaList.findThreeRecords(2);
        System.out.println(res);
        //This will print [3 John 90, 2 Mike 80, 4 Davi 30]
    }

}
```